# Создаётся лишний массив при использовании map

Tags: javascript

У меня есть основной массив:

```
mainArr = [
  {
    label: 'address',
    value: [
      [{name: 'item 1'}, {name: 'item 2'}, ...],
      [{name: 'item 3'}, {name: 'item 4'}, ...]
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

мне необходимо создать новый обьект который будет выглядеть так:

```
newObj = {
  address: [
    [{name: 'item 1'}, {name: 'item 2'}, ...],
    [{name: 'item 3'}, {name: 'item 4'}, ...]
  ],
  ...
}
```

проблема с моим кодов в том что он создаёт один лишний массив и получаеться такой результат:

```
newObj = {
      address: [
        [
           [{name: 'item 1'}, {name: 'item 2'}, ...],
           [{name: 'item 3'}, {name: 'item 4'}, ...]
       ]
      ],
      ...
    }
```

как можно решить эту проблему?

```
const newMatchesArray = mainArr.map((elem) => {
    const addressArr = elem
                    .filter((item) => item.label.toLowerCase() === 'address')
                    .map((item) => item.value);

    let newItem = {};
    newItem.address = addressArr;
    return newItem;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newItem.address = addressArr[0];
```